# How much RAM is supported by a computer?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I would like to know what is the maximum ram I could add to a computer, in my case a laptop.

Like what points to take into account when buying one, and if of those to leave.

- Processor (Intel i3, i5 o i7) (AMD Thurion, FX, A8, A10)
- Generation (1 ,2 ,3, ... N)

If they are only points like those previously mentioned, or it is better to take note of the model and to see technical revisions, of being thus recommendations exist.

Comment: If you don’t know your system’s specs, use this tool.
http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner

Comment: I saw some with 32gb, but I doubt a laptop can go much higher.

Comment: -1 obviously different computers support different amounts of RAM.  You couldn't (generally! or at least in 99.99% of cases!) put 16GB RAM in a computer from 20 years ago.

Comment: Also sometimes a computer's spec seems fine but it runs slow. Best thing is make sure you have a good returns policy and can try it first. Personally if it was not a laptop i'd build it and then if it was slow i'd change parts.. For a laptop i'd make sure the returns policy was good.

Comment: @cybernard my laptop is old, Acer 5536, I bought it in 2009

Comment: @mic84 Can you put your comment as answer, that is all i looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested or need to learn a bit more about ram and memory without going to deep into it, the computer ram sales sites generally have OK 'How find out about sections'.
 You can fill out the forms to get your order or you can use the free scanners and downloadable tools to scan your computer and tell you the right type and size of memory your computer uses and can use.
E.G. at [Crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/)
and for the [Scanner tool download page](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner)
and here at [Memory stock](http://www.memorystock.com/)
and the info page at [Memory stock index](http://www.computermemoryupgrade.net/index1.html)

These scanners are good as the company is hoping to sell to you and not have returns and refunds.
They are also free to use buying or not.